# How can I implement time versions in a relational database system

Tags: database

I am building a system for tracking the lifecycle of it systems. It must be possible to lookup every old version of a system.

The version-system must be able to handle following use-cases:

UC1: The User wants the current version of a system identified by it's hostname

UC2: The User wants the current Version and every future Version

UC3: The User wants the whole lifecycle of a System identified by it's hostname

In our company it is possible that two systems share the same hostname, but than one is old and not running anymore.

When changes are made than there are two possible actions: the system is changing, maybe more diskspace or it is shut down, than we need a new version. Otherwise, if there is incorrect data in a version, than the user is able to correct this version and doesn't get a new version.

In the current model there is a combined primary key of guid and version, in some of the cases this is very useful because there will be ralations where the version matters and there will be somme where the version doesn't matter.

I've read about a model which works like a block-chain, so a new version has a parent ID of his privious version. But I think it is expensive if you have a relation to an old version and want to load the newest version.

On the other hand it could be possible that we have to insert a version between other versions, e.g. we have a shutdown version in 6 month and before that we need more disk space.

I'm totally unsure how the versioning could be possible without slowing down the database.

Comment: Do yu have any specific question about this? What kind of "slowing down the database" do you fear?

Comment: Hi, my fear is that I have to make to many joins to find the data I'm searching for or even worse i have to make too many selects for a record